# How do I return a user input directory as a function in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm just learning Python and I'm trying to build a program to unzip a file at a specified location and then move it to another designated location.

I've created a function that asks the user to search for the designated file containing the .zip file using `filedialog.askopenfilename`. This was then supposed to be stored so that it can be sent to another function which would unzip the file since I didn't want it to be automatically unzipped upon receiving the location.

The problem that I'm facing is I'm not sure how to pass and store the location directory to be used by other functions. Or is there a better way to do this?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import zipfile
import os
import pathlib

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('450x350+350+150')  # setting the screen size
root.title('Unzip file')  # setting the title name


# Gets the user to choose the location of the zip file
def input_path():
    input_file_dir = filedialog.askdirectory()
    return input_file_dir  # how do I return this so that it can be passed to the extract_zip


# extracting the zip
def extract_zip(input_file_dir):
    os.chdir(input_file_dir)  # changing file directory to location of zip folder
    for file in os.listdir():  # get the list of files
        if zipfile.is_zipfile(file):  # if it is a zipfile, extract it
            with zipfile.ZipFile(file) as item:  # treat the file as a zip
                item.extractall()  # extract it in the working directory


# Setting the frame size to insert all our widgets
frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='black')
frame.pack(fill='both', expand=False)

# Setting the title in the frame
label = tk.Label(frame, text='Unzip Files', font='Arial 36 bold', fg='#948a54', bg='black', pady=50)
label.pack(side='top')

openFile = tk.Button(frame, text='Choose location of zip file', font='14', command=input_path)
openFile.pack(side='top')


unzipButton = tk.Button(frame, text='Unzip', width=19, font='14', command=extract_zip)
unzipButton.pack(side='top', pady=15)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you provide any code relevant to the issue and what you have tried?

Comment: I've added the code but I don't think it's any good

Answer (score 0):

You can utilise `classes` and `self` variables, which you can access across functions within the class. I have updated a bit of code to enable this to work, if you are not familiar with `classes` and `self`, I have included some links below to read up on how they function.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import zipfile
import os
import pathlib

class unzip():

    def __init__(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.geometry('450x350+350+150')  # setting the screen size
        root.title('Unzip file')  # setting the title name

        frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='black')
        frame.pack(fill='both', expand=False)

        # Setting the title in the frame
        label = tk.Label(frame, text='Unzip Files', font='Arial 36 bold', fg='#948a54', bg='black', pady=50)
        label.pack(side='top')

        openFile = tk.Button(frame, text='Choose location of zip file', font='14', command=self.input_path)
        openFile.pack(side='top')


        unzipButton = tk.Button(frame, text='Unzip', width=19, font='14', command=self.extract_zip)
        unzipButton.pack(side='top', pady=15)


        root.mainloop()

    # Gets the user to choose the location of the zip file
    def input_path(self):
        self.input_file_dir = filedialog.askdirectory()


    # extracting the zip
    def extract_zip(self):

        print(self.input_file_dir)
        os.chdir(self.input_file_dir)  # changing file directory to location of zip folder
        for file in os.listdir():  # get the list of files
            if zipfile.is_zipfile(file):  # if it is a zipfile, extract it
                with zipfile.ZipFile(file) as item:  # treat the file as a zip
                    item.extractall()  # extract it in the working directory



if __name__ == '__main__':
    unzip()
```

[Python Classes](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp)

[Self in Python](https://www.edureka.co/blog/self-in-python/)

[Official Documentation - Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)